# Why won't my listView clear?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am having a problem with my listView, when I click the clear button I expect my list to clear (obviously) but for some reason my list is not clearing here is the code below, any help would be appreciated. Thank You

MainClass

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults;
private FloatingActionButton add;
private FloatingActionButton clear;
ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
final Context context = this;
String time1, people1, description1, mDate, hour, minute, MeridiemIndicator, dateNumber;
int Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    searchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    final CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.custom_row_view, results);
    lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    add = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            dialogMethod(lv1);
        }


    });

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            adapter.remove(results.get(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
    lv1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            adapter.remove(results.get(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialogMethod(lv1);

            return false;
        }


    });
    clear = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            results.clear();
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    });
}

private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults() {


    SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setName("  Meeting With: " + people1);
    sr1.setTimeOfMeeting("  Starts At: " + time1);
    sr1.setDescription("  Details: " + description1);
    sr1.setDate("  Date: " + mDate);
    sr1.setDateNumber(dateNumber);
    results.add(sr1);
    Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<SearchResults>() {
        public int compare(SearchResults x, SearchResults y) {
            return Integer.parseInt(x.getDateNumber()) - Integer.parseInt(y.getDateNumber());
        }
    });


    return results;
}
```

Here is my custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, int custom_row_view, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
    super(context,custom_row_view,results);

    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtTimeOfMeeting = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeOfMeeting);
        holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtTimeOfMeeting.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTimeOfMeeting());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.txtDate.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDate());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtTimeOfMeeting;
    TextView txtDescription;
    TextView txtDate;
   }
}
```

The problem more specifically is in the main method just below the floating action button "clear". Again thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clear list setadapter again.

```
  clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        results.clear();
        CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.custom_row_view, results);
lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


});
```

OR

Clear adapter

```
myAdapter.clear();
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I have to wait 8 more minutes but I definitely will